# R get the mean data frame across multiple dataframes inside a list

Tags: r, list, for-loop

I have stored my 50-times iterations in a list. Within each iteration, there are 3 dataframes, lets say, A, B and C. What I want to get is an mean across the 50 iterations for each of the A, B and C. In other words, my ideal output would be 3 dataframes, each is the mean across the 50 iterations. I have searched but did not find a solution as I have multiple dataframes within a list. My list looks like this:

E.g., the 13th iteration

```
[[13]]
[[13]][[1]]

     [,1]      [,2]      [,3]     [,4]       [,5]     [,6]     [,7]

[1,] 0.380046 0.4902323 0.4796915 1.195202 0.00000000 1.000000   50
[2,] 0.400070 0.4948018 0.3960589 1.120469 0.00000000 1.000000   50
[3,] 0.400070 0.4902323 0.4796915 1.195202 0.02002400 1.020024   50

[[13]][[2]]

     [,1]      [,2]      [,3]     [,4]       [,5]     [,6]     [,7]
[1,] 0.440458 0.5010251 0.2344312 1.016609 0.00000000 1.000000   50
[2,] 0.460404 0.4961009 0.1529311 1.002198 0.00000000 1.000000   50
[3,] 0.460404 0.5010251 0.2344312 1.016609 0.01994600 1.019946   50


[[13]][[3]]
     [,1]      [,2]      [,3]     [,4]       [,5]     [,6]     [,7]

[4,] 0.440458 0.5010251 0.2344312 1.016609 0.00000000 1.000000   50
[5,] 0.460404 0.4961009 0.1529311 1.002198 0.00000000 1.000000   50
[6,] 0.460404 0.4961009 0.2344312 1.016609 0.02427493 1.014447   50
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example, your attempt(s) at a solution, and the desired result.

Comment: You could try `lapply(lst, function(x) Reduce(`+`, x)/length(x))`

Comment: @akrun Thank you akrun, what does the + mean here? what should i input for the +?

Comment: I meant `Reduce("+", x)`  Used the backquotes which got removed.  It is for summing up the corresponding elements